# How to setup different subdomains in Flask (using blueprints)?

Tags: python, flask-restful, flask

I have a Flask application running at https://app.mydomain.com.

The blueprints look like this:

```
app.register_blueprint(main)
app.register_blueprint(account, url_prefix='/account')
app.register_blueprint(users, url_prefix='/users')
app.register_blueprint(boxes, url_prefix='/boxes')
app.register_blueprint(api_1_0, url_prefix='/api/v1.0')
```

The URLs look like this:

- https://app.mydomain.com
- https://app.mydomain.com/account
- https://app.mydomain.com/users
- ...

I want to move the `api_1_0` route from https://app.mydomain.com/api/v1.0 to https://api.mydomain.com, how should I modify the routes and how should I set `app.config['SERVER_NAME']`?

`example.com` (without any subdomain) is another site entirely, otherwise I would get rid of the `app` subdomain.

So, I want `app` to be the default subdomain for all blueprints except `api_1_0` which should be `api`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you want your Flask application to handle multiple subdomains, you should set `app.config['SERVER_NAME']` to the root domain. Then apply `app` as the default subdomain and overriding it in `api` blueprint registration.

The way to do this would be something like that I suppose:

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'mydomain.com'
app.url_map.default_subdomain = "app"
app.register_blueprint(account, url_prefix='/account')
app.register_blueprint(users, url_prefix='/users')
app.register_blueprint(boxes, url_prefix='/boxes')
app.register_blueprint(api_1_0, subdomain='api')
```